# Big O Notation Calculation

Tags: c++, data-structures, big-o

I'm stuck determining the big o notation for the below fragmented code, the given expression is part of I'm trying to figure out. I know given two plain, default `for` loops results in `O(n^2)` but the latter is entirely different. Here are the instructions.

The algorithm of

```
for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
{
  for (k = j; k < n; k++)
  {
  }
}
```

will result in a number of iterations of given by the expression:

```
= n + (n-1) + (n-2) + (n-3) + ........ + (n - n)
```

- Reduce the above series expression to an algebraic expression, without summation.
- After determining the algebraic expression express the performance in Big O Notation.

Comment: It's `n*(n-1)/2` which is also `O(n^2)`

Comment: [Triangle numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) are a lot of mathsy fun! But also, still dominated by the `n^2` term: `(1/2)n^2 + (1/2)n`.

Comment: @john: why would the second `for` loop be `n * ((n-1)/2)`?

Comment: Learn arithmetic progression, for example here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression

Comment: The second loop is not `n * (n-1) / 2` by itself, but whatever statements inside it will be executed that number of times.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this method (supposedly applied by Gauss when he was a wee lad).

If you sum all the numbers twice, you have

```
     1   +   2   +   3   + ... +  n
+    n   + (n-1) + (n-2) + ... +  1
—————————————————————————————————————--
   (n+1) + (n+1) + (n+1) + ... + (n+1)   = n(n+1)
```

Thus,

```
1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n = n(n+1)/2
```

and `n(n+1)/2` is `(n^2)/2 + n/2`, so it is in `O(n^2)`.